# Add Quotes from User Given String

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line, command-prompt

## Introduction

I made some script to Automate user Folder Takeown and Grant User permission using Icacls. The user will give a value via CMD Script using

```
set /p MCust=
set MCustom=^"MCust^"
```

but using that, the path still doesnt have any quotation. instead Takeown and Icacls recognize the spaced path as 2 different path. For example :

```
E:\Program Files\Adobe\
```

The result will :

```
"E:\Program": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
"Files\Adobe": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

## Problem

Because of that, i really cant use Escape Quotes. I really need some auto-quotation inside the script. So i manage to give three quotation. Like the code below :

```
set /p Path=
set Paths="""%Path%"""
```

Using that, its indeed quoting the Directory String. But still result some error even though the path is already quoted as i can see fromt the error:

```
"E:\Program Files\Adobe": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Error above is the result of executing the Takeown and icacls command :

```
for /d %%a in ("%MCustom%") do @takeown /F %%a )
for /d %%b in ("%MCustom%") do @icacls %%b /grant Users:F
```

Is there any better way to add quotation for user given string?
Anyway here's the script i struggle with :

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
echo.
echo ============================================================
echo Put Your Custom Path here..
echo ============================================================
echo.
set /p "MCust=Path: "

REM the User will pasted the path using drag-point or either copy paste from the directory itself without any Quotation

Set "MCustom="%MCust%""

REM using new variable that has Escape Quote, it can be either ^"%MCust%^% or anything related.

echo %MCustom%

for /d %%b in ("%MCustom%") do @icacls "%%b" /gran Users:F Administrator:F

REM those icacls command will return as error :
"E:\Program": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
"Files\Adobe": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Comment: Why the [tag:powershell] tag?

Comment: First, please do not use, and therefore overwrite, the important system variable `Path`, use something like `myPath` instead. `Set "myPath="%myPath:"=%""`, should remove any user added doublequotes, whilst enclosing it in them too. This means that you should only have one set enclosing the path regardless of whether the end user included them or not. Please note however, that `Set /P` allows your end user to enter nothing, or anything at all, including invalid characters for file paths, and even malicious strings. I would therefore advise you to validate the variable value, before using it.

Comment: Thanks for commenting but i dont use that variable name in my real script! Dont worry! :). And yeah, the problem is the path have some white spaces and there's no quote what so ever from user given string. I just wanted to add some automation so the path from the user can be quoted automaticly and pass it into another command such as takeown and icacls @Compo

Comment: You should not include quotes in the valuable values, you should better quote the paths where you use them: `set "VAR=E:\Program Files\Adobe"` (no quotes in the value, verify with `set VAR`), then `icacls "%VAR%" …`…

Comment: Where is the relation between the `path` variable and your FOR-Loops?

Comment: Unfortunately, i have been trying that also. quoted "%VAR%" returned as destination path without quotation by the icacls command. Its simply recognize as 2 different path as i mention on the thread. @aschipfl

Comment: I use "MCustom" path variable because i wanted the "MCust" path string to be quoted. That's why i use some Escape Quotation by using some caret ^. Unfortunately, its also doesnt work. but somehow when i use echo on MCustom variable, the string becomes quoted but not by icacls. Its weird @jeb

Comment: Well, I don't know what you've tried, but I can't reproduce the issue you describe; is the trailing `\ `in your path causing issues?

Comment: I have added the script into the thread now, so anyone can test it @aschipfl

Comment: If you are really using `E:\Program Files\Adobe\ `as the path, including the trailing backslash, the quoted string `"E:\Program Files\Adobe\"` is going to be problematic for both commands, `icacls` and `takeown`, since both use `\ `as an escape character, so the trailing `"` becomes escaped, giving an invalid path. Therefore, either remove the trailing backslash, double it or append a `.`…

Comment: Concerning your way of quotation: it is just terrible! There is no need to over-quote the path, simply use `set /P MCustom=""`, and then `for /D %%b in ("%MCustom%") do @… "%%~b" …`…

Comment: Yep, i knew its terrible but i thought both command returns the path as unquoted, that's why i wanted to add some quote at the first and the end of the string. Anyway thanks for the help! @aschipfl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `"%%~b"`:

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
set /p "MCustom=Path: "

for /d %%b in ("%MCustom%") do icacls "%%~b" /gran Users:F Administrator:F
```

Btw.: It's always a good idea to use `echo on`, when parts of the code don't work…

Comment: Unfortunately, its still giving me error : ERROR: File or Directory not found.
ERROR: File or Directory not found.
"E:\Program /grant Users:F Administrator:F Administrators:F: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files. But dont worry, those code snippet is just an example :) @jeb